# Choosing a specific row in a table in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model, rails-activerecord

I have a migration and model with a table called medications. I need to pick a specific row from the medications table. I also am trying to filter out all medications that don't have the current user's id.

Here is the current code I have.

```
Medication.find(:name, :conditions => { :user_id => current_user.id }, :order => "Medication.name")
```

I know this isn't complete, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I said I wanted to filter out medications that don't have the current user id. Double negative.

Comment: I use rails version 4

Comment: Do you want to pick *all* medications for a given user_id or *a specific row*? What is the specification? The latest? With a specific `id`?

Comment: I just want to pick one to use as a title, I want to be able to specify first or x  result that it finds to use for multiple titles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load the first medication for a specific `user_id` like this (assuming that your `medications` table has an `user_id`):

```
Medication.where(user_id: current_user.id).order(:name).first
```

When our `User` model has a `belongs_to :medications` it can be simplified to:

```
current_user.medications.order(:name).first
```

When you want to load the e.g. 5th medication just add an offset of 4:

```
current_user.medications.order(:name).offest(4).first
```

Or load all medications and iterate through them:

```
current_user.medications.limit(10).each do |medication|
  puts medication.name
end
```

When you want to output the first ten medications on a website you would do something like this:

```
# in the controller
@medications = current_user.medications.order(:name).limit(10)

# in the view
<ul>
  <% @medications.each do |medication| %>
    <li><%= medication.name %></li>
  < end %>
</ul>
```

The finder syntax you use is deprecated and was replaced in Rails 4. See [Rails Guide about querying the database](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#conditions).

Comment: Thats awesome, but how could I do it for the second, third, or 50th result?

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you again, but this just needs one more tweak that I'm having trouble with. This outputs some weird text because its outputting the medication, not the name. It looks like this.... http://i.imgur.com/LWcGgj1.png

Comment: Thank you very much for the continued help, people like you make stack overflow great. It still doesn't quite work, that new method shows all of the medications, not just specific result.

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect use case for a `has_many :through` association if you don't already have it set up.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :prescriptions # or whatever
  has_many :medications, :through => :prescriptions
end

class Prescription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :medication
end

class Medication < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :prescriptions
  has_many :users, :through => :prescriptions
end
```

Now you can do stuff like `@user.medications` to retrieve only that user's medications, `@user.medications.find(params[:medication_id]` to find a specific one within a user's assigned medications, and `@user.medications << Medication.find_by(name: 'Aspirin')` to add a medication to a user, and so on.

This is a basic overview of this technique, but it's a basic Rails concept so there's plenty of information on use cases close to whatever you may be trying to do.

Comment: That still just outputs a whole row, not a part of it.

Comment: I didn't include any view behavior, it doesn't output anything. If you just want the name, you would use ‘@medication.name‘ like normal

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem and I have decided to post the answer in case anybody else seems to have a similar problem.

I ended up not putting anything in my controller or adding anything new to my models. I just used this line of code in the view.

```
<%= Medication.offset(0).where(:user_id => current_user.id).pluck(:name).first %>
```

I couldn't have done it without the support of everyone who posted, Thank you!

Comment: That's more specific than what you described.

Comment: Could be written as `<%= current_user.medications.first.name %>`